# UIImagePickerController not showing up in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

For some odd reason is my UIImagePickerController not showing up running this code ? Can you see the problem ?

this is on my Iphone 5 - I only get a black screen appearing - and I cannot do any interaction

```
var pictureViewer = new PictureViewController((APTask)GetItem(e.IndexPath.Row), e.IndexPath);
parent.NavigationController.PresentViewController(pictureViewer, true, null);
```

This is picture classview class:

```
public class PictureViewController : UIViewController, IUINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    private UIImagePickerController _imagePicker;
    private APTask _task;
    private NSIndexPath _indexPath;
    private UIImage _image;
    private NSDictionary _imageMetadata;

    public PictureViewController(APTask task, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        this._task = task;
        this._indexPath = indexPath;
    }


    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        _imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController ();

        // set our source to the photo library
        _imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;

        _imagePicker.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext;
        // set what media types
//      _imagePicker.MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes (UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary);

        _imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += Handle_FinishedPickingMedia;
        _imagePicker.Canceled += Handle_Canceled;

        _imagePicker.Delegate = this;

        PresentViewController(_imagePicker, true, null);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to present the `UIImagePickerController` at the competition of presenting your `pictureViewer` as it is a `UIViewController`

Your code:

```
parent.NavigationController.PresentViewController(pictureViewer, true, null);
```

Would need to not pass `null` for the competition handler. You could expose a pubic method on your `PictureViewController` class that does the creation/presentation of the `UIImagePickerController` and pass that `Action` (method) as the handler...

But why create/present an empty `UIViewController` just to than cover it up with a `UIImagePickerController`, here is how I do it...

**Note:** This code also handles iPad presentation properly and if you are requesting the camera within the Simulator it defaults to the `PhotoLibrary` to avoid the native ObjC exception.

```
public partial class myViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImagePickerController _imagePickerController;

    public myViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) { }

    partial void myButtonTouch(UIButton sender)
    {
        ImagePickerController(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera);
    }

    public void ImagePickerController(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType)
    {
        if (_imagePickerController == null)
            _imagePickerController = new UIImagePickerController();
        if (Runtime.Arch == Arch.DEVICE) // No camara on Simulator
            _imagePickerController.SourceType = sourceType;
        else
            if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
                _imagePickerController.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) // Handle ipad correctly 
        {
            if (_imagePickerController.SourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
                _imagePickerController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
            else
                _imagePickerController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
        }
        else
        {
            _imagePickerController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext;
        }

        _imagePickerController.Canceled += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Picker Cancelled");
            _imagePickerController.DismissViewController(true, null);
        };
        _imagePickerController.FinishedPickingMedia += (object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            _imagePickerController.DismissViewController(true, null);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ReferenceUrl);
            if (_imagePickerController.SourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
            {
                // Newly-captured media, save it to the Camera Roll on the device or ....
            }
            else
            {
                // Existing media seleted, do something with it....
            }
        };

        var mainWindow = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var viewController = mainWindow?.RootViewController;
        while (viewController?.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            viewController = viewController.PresentedViewController;
        }
        if (viewController == null)
            viewController = this;
        _imagePickerController.View.Frame = viewController.View.Frame;
        viewController.PresentViewController(_imagePickerController, true, () => { Console.WriteLine("Complete"); });
    }
}
```

*Note: You can extract out the `ImagePickerController` method and add it to as static method somewhere to reuse as `while (viewController?.PresentedViewController != null)` code section will always find the correct context in which to present the modal controller.*

Comment: Thx a lot SushiHangover - I did :       `code` parent.NavigationController.PresentViewController(pictureViewer, true, delegate  {pictureViewer.Present();});   but I'm not able to dismiss the pictureViewer - eg.  `code` void Handle_Canceled (object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Console.WriteLine ("picker cancelled");
   this._imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
  } - do you have any ideas ? (just a black screen if I cancel)

Comment: @TheSnakeWizard `Black Screen`: what type of `UIModalPresentationStyle` are you using for your `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: PresentViewController(_imagePicker, true, null);

Comment: I've tried both _imagePicker.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext; and commenting the line out - can you see the error :)

Comment: works fine for me, a black screen mean you have nothing in the view... try just setting the current controller's view to a white background after you dismiss the image picker (`this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;`)

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover - I guess i was panicking a bit, I just had to dismiss parent.DismissVievController